# Is this a valid way to think of decomposable $k$-forms?

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, tensors, differential-forms, exterior-algebra

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space and $\eta \in \Lambda^k(V^\ast)$ be decomposable and non-zero. Then there exists covectors $\omega^1,\dots,\omega^k$ such that
$$\eta(v_1, \dots, v_k) = \omega_1 \wedge \dots \wedge \omega_k (v_1, \dots, v_k) = \det \left(\omega^i(v_j)\right).$$
Fix a basis for $V$, I will now treat covectors like vectors.
Define the matrices 
\begin{align}
\Omega &=  (\omega_i^j) \\
V &= (v_j^i).
\end{align}

Then
$$\eta(v_1, \dots, v_k) = \det(\Omega V)$$
Define $S=\text{span}(\omega^1, \dots, \omega^k)$ and let $E$ be a $k\times n$ matrix whose rows form an orthonormal basis for $S$.
Then $\Omega = \Omega E^T E$ so
\begin{align}
\eta(v_1, \dots, v_k) &= \det(\Omega E^T E V)\\
&= \det(\Omega E^T) \det(E V) \\
&= \det(E\Omega^T) \det(E V) \\
&= \text{Vol}_S(\omega^1,\dots,\omega^k) \text{Vol}_S(v_1, \dots, v_k)
\end{align}
Where $\text{Vol}_S(u_1, \dots, u_k)$ gives the $S$-projected volume of the parallelotope spanned by $u_1, \dots, u_k$. Assuming I didn't make any mistakes, is there an analogous viewpoint for non-decomposable $k$-covectors?

**Edit:**

Here is another question that probably has an obvious answer. Is every $k$-covector decomposable in the right basis?

Comment: The answer to your edit is no:  The covector $\omega = dx_1 \wedge dx_2 + dx_3 \wedge dx_4$ in $\mathbb{R}^4$ is not decomposable with respect to any basis.  The idea is that if $\omega$ was decomposable, then $\omega^2 = \omega \wedge \omega = 0$ because it repeats some basis vector.  However, $\omega\wedge \omega = 2 dx_1\wedge dx_2\wedge dx_3\wedge dx_4 \neq 0$.

Comment: @JasonDeVito, Thanks, I also found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1784312/deciding-whether-a-form-in-the-exterior-power-bigwedgek-v-is-decomposable) which basically answers my whole question. So I guess my best option is to think of non-decomposable $k$-forms as linear combinations of decomposable ones.